# Kineticjs and adding invert filter

Tags: javascript, kineticjs, imagefilter

I have a kineticjs Image and I want o invert it. I do the following:

```
backgroundImage.filters([Kinetic.Filters.Invert]);
backgroundImage.draw();
//BackgroundImage is inside a backgroundGroup so I draw it too
backgroundGroup.draw();
// I also draw the stage
stage.draw();
```

But nothing happens. I don't know if all those draws are necessary, but even so filter doesn't seem to apply.

Comment: I hope this will help [html5-canvas-kineticjs-invert-image-tutorial](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-invert-image-tutorial/)

Comment: Yes it did, I read in git that it is necessary to call cache() method, something I didn't do. Thank you.